# Shell script which runs mono_service.exe as a background task

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, mono

When I start an Ubuntu Linux 16.04 process with `/usr/lib/4.5/mono_service.exe AudioRecorder.exe` it returns right way. But, when I write a bash shell script with one line:

```
exec /usr/lib/4.5/mono_service.exe AudioRecorder.exe
```

it never returns until I kill the process and remove the lock.

Should I modify this bash shell script to run as a background task like this,

```
exec /usr/lib/4.5/mono_service.exe AudioRecorder.exe &
```

so that the shell script returns immediately?